# Jquery UI blank autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**What:**
I want to crate an autocomplete, where admin can select a user from dropdown list.
Also, I want to display the ID of selected user on my page.

**Problem:** The problem I'm getting is the blank dropdown autocomplete field, and I don't know how to solve this. Also the ID is not updating.

**The code**

Javascript:

```
// Values
var names = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max'},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'John'},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Gray'},
{
    id: 4,
    name: 'Bob'},
{
    id: 5,
    name: 'Terminator'}
];

// Autocomplete start..
$('#suggested-users').autocomplete({
    source: names,
    select: function() {
        $('#user-id').html(ui.item.id);
    }
});​
```

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="suggested-users">
        <hr>
        <p><strong>ID:</strong><span id="user-id"></span></p>
    </body>

</html>​
```

**JSFiddle:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBfL2/)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: When using an array of objects as the source, you need to make the properties `label` and `value`, not `id` and `name`. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Thanks, now the dropdown is working, but the value is displaying in input field. How can it display it in span element? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZBfL2/1/)**

```
var opt;
// Values
var names = [
    {
    label: 'Max',
    value: 1},
{
    label: 'John',
    value: 2},
{
    label: 'Gray',
    value: 3},
{
    label: 'Bob',
    value: 4},
{
    label: 'Terminator',
    value: 5}
];

// Autocomplete start..
$('#suggested-users').autocomplete({
    source: names,
    select: function(e, ui) {
        $('#user-id').html(ui.item.value);
        opt = ui.item.label;
    },
    close: function() {
        $('#suggested-users').val(opt);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use objects with attributes `label` and `value`.  [Source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).